# IE9 windows7 install problems

Tags: windows-7, installation, internet-explorer-9

I've just tried to install IE9 on my windows 7 machine, and I'm having a nightmare.

The installation finished, but when I try to run IE9, the window opens, the blue loading circle spins, then the window shuts. Same happens after a restart.

I wonder if it might be something to do with incompatibility with the virtual PC XP I have installed (IE9 won't run in XP), although I don't really see why it should affect it.

And what's worse is that I have not been able to get back to IE8 again. I've uninstalled IE9, and IE8 is no longer there. I even ran the IE8 install again, but it's still not there- iexplore.exe has not been created.

Any suggestions?

*---UPDATE---*

*I've managed to get back to IE8 again now- thanks. Has anyone got any ideas as to why IE9 won't run for me?*

Comment: Is there any information in the event log?

Comment: Just looked. No errors or warnings. The install apparently completed without erroring.

Comment: Is your Windows up to date? IE9 is provided via WU as well. You might try installing from there and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: Tried installing via WU. Again, install completes without error, but IE crashes when I try to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling the IE9 update will restore IE8 :

1. Close all programs.
2. Click Start, and then click Control Panel.
3. Click Uninstall a Program under the Programs category
4. In the Tasks pane, click View installed updates.
5. In the list of installed updates, double-click Windows Internet Explorer 9.
6. In the Uninstall an update dialog box, click Yes.
   Note If you are prompted for an administrator password or for confirmation, type the password, or click Continue.
7. Follow the instructions to uninstall Internet Explorer 9.
8. When the uninstall program is finished, restart your computer.
9. After you restart your computer, open Internet Explorer.
10. Click About Internet Explorer on the Help menu. If Internet Explorer 7 or 8 appears in the About Internet Explorer dialog box, then you have successfully completed the uninstall.

If this doesn't work, do a system restore to before the installation of IE9.

Comment: I had already tried uninstalling IE9 by this method already, and it left me without any IE. However after reinstalling IE9 and uninstalling again, it did work and I was left with a working IE8. Thanks. Shame I can't get IE9 to work though.

Comment: Something probably went wrong with some previous update to IE8, which left Windows incapable of correctly installing IE9 over it (I wouldn't think this has to do with a virus infection, but check anyway). I don't think IE9 is worth a complete re-installation of Windows?

Comment: No, I'm sure you're right- IE9 can't be that great. Trouble is, I really should have it installed so I can test my web app still works on it.

Comment: You can do that using a virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

Try loading IE into safemode if you can. It sounds like an addon is causing it to crash.

http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/run-internet-explorer-9-without-addons-in-safe-mode/

If it works, goto Internet Options from the control panel > Advanced > Reset

Comment: IE9 still crashes in safemode.

Comment: Goto Control Panel > Internet Options > Advanced & reset it. Go back & Click 'Use software rendering instead of GPU rendering'. It should be at the top.

Comment: Sorry. No difference.

Comment: How about running IE and IE (No addons) mode when Windows is also in the safe mode with Networking Enabled?

Comment: Just tried that, but nope. Same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is system restore enabled? I'd roll bacck to the snapshot it took before installing IE9..

Comment: I've got IE8 back now, so I can't test this method. But it sounds like it would work. Thanks. Shame I can't get IE9 to work though.